# How to assign cell value for table view using dictionary?

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary

I have been trying to populate a table view with first names from a plist dictionary. Getting errors while configuring cell value.

My Code:

```
// Created a function to get plist dictionary values

func getSwiftArrayFromPlist() -> (Array<Dictionary<String,String>>) {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Sheet1", ofType: "plist")
    var arr: NSArray?
    arr = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)
    return (arr as? Array<Dictionary<String,String>>)!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //var mainGroup = [String]()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let array1 = getSwiftArrayFromPlist().count
    return array1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    //var key   = Array(self.array.keys)[indexPath.row]

    var key = getSwiftArrayFromPlist()["firstname"]
    var value = getSwiftArrayFromPlist()[key]
    return cell
}
```

Getting error at var key:

> Cannot subscript a value of type 'Array>' with an index of type 'String'

My goal is to get a list of first name in table view (key is "first name" value is that actual first name.

Comment: try to call this method(getSwiftArrayFromPlist()) from viewdidload n store in array then use that array for populating the data into table view

Answer (score 0):

The return type of getSwiftArrayFromPlist() is an array. But you are trying to access it like a dictionary using the key "firstname"

It should be:-

```
var key = getSwiftArrayFromPlist()[indexPath.row]["firstname"]
var value = getSwiftArrayFromPlist()[indexPath.row][key!]
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much! Actually I was struggling a bit after incorporating your code for key. I found out that Var key returns the actual first name, so when that gets passed to var value as a parameter, it crashes the application since I end up getting a nil. So I passed the "key" as cell text value. All set. Boy, that took all of four days!